# Weather app Javascript isn't working

Tags: javascript

I ve got nothing in console. It should change contain of html to the information taken from openweatherapp for this zip code(i check this zip and it exists and function updateByZip creates good link). First code is JS and second HTML.
JS

```
var temp;
var loc;
var humidity;
var icon;

function bg() {
  var backs = ["http://wallpapercave.com/wp/JthAGYd.jpg", "http://www.desktopwallpaperhd.net/wallpapers/20/b/welshdragon-landscapes-cometh-background-204971.jpg", "http://s1.picswalls.com/wallpapers/2014/08/08/scottish-landscape-desktop-backgrounds_015751372_152.jpg", "http://img.wallpaperfolder.com/f/4313075B95B2/amazing-winter-backgrounds-6770538-landscape.jpg"];
  var ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * (backs.length));
  $('body').css("background-image", "url('" + backs[ran] + "')")
    //document.body.style.background = "url/'('" + backs[0] + "') no-repeat";
}

function tempCF() {
  var x = document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML;
  var y = document.getElementById("CF").innerHTML;
  x = parseInt(x);
  if (y == "C") {
    x = Math.floor((9 / 5 * x + 32));
    document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = x;
    document.getElementById("CF").innerHTML = "F"
  } else if (y == "F") {
    x = Math.floor((x - 32) * 5 / 9);
    document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = x;
    document.getElementById("CF").innerHTML = "C";
  };
}

function updateByZip(zip) {
  var APPID = "55e568aa04114cdf3dc4b90c9ae0a60c";
  var url = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=" + zip + "&APPID=" + APPID;
  sendRequest(url);
}

function sendRequest(url) {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
      var weather = {};
      weather.temp = data.main.temp;
      weather.humidity = data.main.pressure;
      weather.loc = data.name;
      //weather.icon = data.weather[0].id;
      update(weather);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

function update(weather) {
  document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = weather.temp;
  document.getElementById("humidity").innerHTML = weather.humidity;
  document.getElementById("loc").innerHTML = weather.loc;
  //document.getElementById("icon").innerHTML = weather.icon;  
};
window.onload = function() {
  var temp = document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML;
  var loc = document.getElementById("loc").innerHTML;
  var humidity = document.getElementById("humidity").innerHTML;
  //var icon = document.getElementById("icon").innerHTML;
  updateByZip(94040);
  //weather.icon = "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/700175-icon-1-cloud-128.png";
};
```

HTML

```
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body onclick="bg()">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="title"><span id="loc"> Your location</span></div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-ms-4">
          <div class="fircol"><span id="temp">0</span>&deg;<span onclick="tempCF()" id="CF">C</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-ms-4">
          <div class="seccol"><span id="humidity">Rain</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-ms-4">
          <div class="thicol"><span class="icon"><img src= https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/700175-icon-1-cloud-128.png></img></span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't see anything in the console? [Because I do.](https://jsfiddle.net/9khmmrdg/)

Comment: you are right. i see " too much recursion " problem but i didnt really know why it displays but probably sth in sendRequest()  isnt working. Am i right ?

Comment: You can make this question easier to read and understand by finding [the shortest piece of code that reproduces your problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Your API url is not correct.
You should write:

```
var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=" + zip + "&APPID=" + APPID;
```